# From PDO to SQLSRV

Tags: php, sql-server, database, sqlsrv

I used PDO for MYSql before but now i need to use Microsoft SQL Server Driver for PHP.

I found the manual.
http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php

I use Example #2 to connect to the new SQL database:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php

How do I 'convert' the following (PDO mysql) to work with sqlsrv:

```
$username = 'test';

try {
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database', $username, password);
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT username users WHERE username = :username LIMIT 1');
$stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));

if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
$result = $stmt->fetch();

    echo $result['username'];

} else {
    echo 'Nothing found.';
die();
}
} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Why not using http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php so it will require only minimal changes in your code ?

Comment: So I only need to change: new PDO to new PDO_SQLSRV ?

Comment: No, you will nedd to change DSN (connection string), to inform PDO that you need to use sqlsrv driver, and pass proper named parameters to it, like `new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=$database",$username, $password);`

Comment: Then it says: ERROR: could not find driver.

Comment: I don't think it's possible without sqlsrv_connect

Comment: to use it, you need `sqlsrv_pdo.dll` driver enabled in your php.ini, semms like you only have `sqlsrv.dll`

Comment: I dont have that in my EXT folder. Where can I get the that .dll ?

Comment: I have only enabled: php_sqlsrv_53_nts_vc9.dll - But that is only for the sqlsrv_connect mode.

Comment: Sorry, but if you can't do some research for your own, I don't think I can help you here...

Answer (score 1):

From php.net

> PHP Data Objects (PDO) extension defines a lightweight, consistent
>   interface for accessing databases in PHP.

Since you already use PDO for MySQL, you may consider use the PDO driver for MS SQL like *dev-null-dweller* said. SQLSRV driver is another choice to access MS SQL. But it will require a overhaul of your current PHP code.

[Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server) provide two kinds of PHP drivers for MS SQL:

*php_sqlsrv.dll* provides a unique set of SQLSRV API specified for MS SQL.

*php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll* provides a set of mostly PDO compatible API for MS SQL.

Note your PHP version when downloading the driver:

```
Version 4.0 supports PHP 7.0+ on Windows and Linux
Version 3.2 supports PHP 5.6, 5.5, and 5.4 on Windows
Version 3.1 supports PHP 5.5 and 5.4 on Windows
Version 3.0 supports PHP 5.4 on Windows
```

And for PHP5.6 Microsoft provide only driver for x86 version. Unofficial X64 driver can find on
http://robsphp.blogspot.tw/2012/06/unofficial-microsoft-sql-server-driver.html

After you download the driver. Copy the version you need to your PHP *ext* folder.
And add the driver name into *php.ini* configurations, for example:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

Then restart the web server.
You can confirm the PDO driver is install correctly if there is a section *pdo_sqlsrv* display by the *phpinfo()* function.

And please note, MS use an different DSN in the PDO constructor. The line

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database', $username, password);
```

Should be changed to

```
$conn = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=$host;Database=$database', $username, password);
```

Then you should not meet the "ERROR: could not find driver" again. Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

After solving the connections issues, you have to convert the SQL statement written using MySQL SQL dialect to T-SQL dialectal (used by SQL Server).

**[1]** SQL Server doesn't has the `LIMIT` clause. More, this clause is not included in SQL standard. Instead, you can use [ROW_NUMBER() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.90%29.aspx). But, in this case, you don't have to use this function because ...

**[2]** ... the `username` column from `users` table should accept only unique values (and, off course, it should be mandatory). So, you have to be sure that you have an unique constraint or an unique index on `username` column. This script will check if you have an unique index on `username` column:

```
DECLARE @TableName SYSNAME=N'dbo.users';
DECLARE @ColumnName SYSNAME=N'username';
SELECT  *
FROM    sys.indexes i
WHERE   i.object_id=OBJECT_ID(@TableName)
AND     i.is_unique=1
AND     EXISTS (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    sys.index_columns ic 
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id=ic.object_id
    AND     c.column_id=ic.column_id
    WHERE   i.object_id=ic.object_id
    AND     i.index_id=ic.index_id
    AND     ic.is_included_column=0
    AND     c.name=@ColumnName
)
AND (
    SELECT  COUNT(*)
    FROM    sys.index_columns ic 
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id=ic.object_id
    AND     c.column_id=ic.column_id
    WHERE   i.object_id=ic.object_id
    AND     i.index_id=ic.index_id
    AND     ic.is_included_column=0
)=1;
```

**[3]** If you have an unique index on `username` column then you don't need to use the `LIMIT 1` clause (or `ROW_NUMBER()` function) because the SQL statement will return always zero(min.) or one(max.) record(s).

**[4]** The SQL statement should be `SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :param`.

Comment: But how do I make a prepared statement?

Comment: @Stefan: My answer regards only the SQL side from your question. I'm not a PHP dev. Check this [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php).